# Are all languages generate by Turing machines countable?

Tags: turing-machines, uncountability

Are all languages generate by Turing machines countable? I know that the set of all TMs are countable, but what about the languages that they generate?

Comment: What does it mean for a Turing machine to "generate" a language? Turing machines normally accept or decide languages.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. All languages, not only those generated by Turing machines, are countable. This is because they are all subsets of $\Sigma^*$, and $\Sigma^*$ itself is countable. However, there are uncountably many languages.

Comment: Not all languages are countable e.g. for language of first order logic one sometimes add constants denoting every element. If such language describes real nunbers then such language is uncountable.

Comment: Right. But in this context the alphabet is always assumed to be finite.